# LibreOffice 4.2.7.2: This document contains macros

Tags: libreoffice, xls

I'm trying to open an .xls document in LibreOffice 4.2.7.2 and getting this error message.

[image]

```
This document contains macros.

Macros may contain viruses. Execution of macros is disabled due to the current macro security setting in Tools - Options - LibreOffice - Security.

Therefore, some functionality may not be available.
```

I can open the file but unable to make any changes in it. Any help to figure out this problem will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: = If you want to get rid of the dialog see the security settings. = those macro's are in Visual Basic (=Microsoft coding language) and that will not work with Linux. = If you want to get rid of the macro's: Edit > Sheet > Move/Copy dialog to copy for all the sheets and save it into a new spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Libreoffice`-->`Security`-->`Macro Security`-->`Low`
Tell me if that solves your problem.
`Note`:This choice will remove any layer of security that you have so be careful what files you are using.

Comment: (+1): Thanks @Marvin for your helpful answer.